# Airflow : How to disable User from editing Variables/Connections in GUI in Production Environment

Tags: airflow

We want to avoid users to manually editing or adding new variables/connections from Airflow GUI in Production. Currently, we are using JSON files which loads all the connections and variables for Airflow.

Can experts guide me on how to achieve this?

Comment: Airflow has [roles](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/security.html?highlight=role#rbac-ui-security). Different parts of UI can be enabled/disabled for a role.

Comment: Thanks @SergiyKolesnikov, Is there any links with steps to implement the same

Comment: I don't know, I've never used that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sergiy's right, you will need to start looking at Airflow's Role Based Access (RBAC) documentation and implement from there. Here's a place to start: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/add-new-role.html